# Why does PostgreSQL reserve fixed amount of memory for the text of the currently executing command?

Tags: postgresql, memory

An excerpt from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-statistics.html):

> `track_activity_query_size (integer)` Specifies the amount of memory reserved to store the text of the currently executing command for each active session, for the pg_stat_activity.query field. If this value is specified without units, it is taken as bytes. The default value is 1024 bytes. This parameter can only be set at server start.

As I understand it, it means that if, for example, `track_activity_query_size` set to 10kB, each session will consume 10kB for the text of the currently executing command regardless of the actual size of the text.

Why is it implemented this way? Would it be too slow to dynamically allocate actually needed amount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This parameter determines how much memory is allocated *in shared memory structures* that contain query texts.

PostgreSQL allocates such shared memory areas at server start and does not change their size later. This is to make the code (that has to work on many operating systems) simple and robust. Once you know `max_connections` and `track_activity_query_size`, you can determine the maximum memory required.